# Using ng-click and scope functions in generated html (angularJs)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope, append

I have a code like this:

```
$scope.printOutRowModel = function(){
    console.log("blah");
}


$scope.createTable = function(name)
{   
        var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('.popup'));
        var content = "";
        content+='<div><hr/>';
        content+='<h4>'+name+'</h4>';
        content+='<table><thead>';
        var columnName = Object.keys($scope.genericModel[name][0]);
    for(var i=0; i<columnName.length; i++)
    {
        if(columnName[i] != "$$hashKey")
        {
        content+='<th>'+columnName[i]+'</th>';
        }
    }
        content+='</thead><tbody>';
    for(var j=0; j<$scope.genericModel[name].length; j++)
    {
        content+='<tr>';
        var value = Object.values($scope.genericModel[name][j]);
        for(var i=0; i<value.length-1; i++)
        {   
        content+='<td>'+value[i]+'</td>';
        }
        content+='</tr>';
        value = null;
    }
        content+='</tbody></table></div>';
        element.html(content);
}
```

So now what I want to do is add the 'ng-click = "printOutRowModel()"' to the generated "td" elements. I tried multiple ways but I doesn't work. When I add it to the any other element that is already in my index.html it does work. So I'm guessing that this generated HTML is not being "compiled" in the scope or something. So is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this directive to your app:

```
app.directive('template', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe("template", function(_newVal) {
            scope.$applyAsync(function() {
                element.html(_newVal);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        });

    };
}]);
```

Then instead of selecting `.popup` class in `createTable` function, do this:

```
<div class="popup" template="{{myTableTpl}}"></div>
```

And change your function to this:

```
$scope.createTable = function(name)
{   
    var content = "";
    // Create your content...
    $scope.myTableTpl = content;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">



<body ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div template="{{tpl}}"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    angular.module('app', [])
      .directive('template', ['$compile',
        function($compile) {
          return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe("template", function(_newVal) {
              scope.$applyAsync(function() {
                element.html(_newVal);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
              });
            });

          };
        }
      ])
      .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.tpl = '<h1>METE-30</h1>'
      });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did that but I dont get my content displayed on the page, but when I press f12 on my page it shows it under template="...". Am I doing something wrong or?

Comment: @i1zivkovic that's weird! do you have any error in console?

Comment: No, I don't acutally. hm..
I tried to move {{myTableTpl}} inside the div tags but it displays the content as the string..
I just started doing angular so I don't really know.

Comment: @i1zivkovic , I change a line in directive, and also put checked code in answer.